# How to download a file using PySide/PyQt from a website

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have this code that receives all of the networking resources of a web page.
I took this code from this [site](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/pyside/2012-October/000786.html) so I don't know how it works but I know that it receives all of the networking resources of a web page, which is what I need.
This is my code:

```
import sys, time
from PySide.QtCore import QUrl, SIGNAL
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebView, QWebSettings
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest

#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
fn_log = 'url_dd.txt'
fp_log = open(fn_log, 'ab+')
class WebPage(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, logger=None, parent=None):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__(parent)

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        sys.stderr.write('Javascritp error at line number %d\n' % (lineNumber))
        sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % (message, ))
        sys.stderr.write('Source ID: %s\n' % (sourceID, ))

class Crawler(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(Crawler, self).__init__(sys.argv)
        self.url = url
        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_page = WebPage()
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)
        self.web_frame = self.web_page.mainFrame()
        self.network = NetworkAccessManager()
        self.web_page.setNetworkAccessManager(self.network)
        self.settings = self.web_page.settings().globalSettings()
        self.settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, False)
        QWebSettings.clearMemoryCaches()
        self.web_view.resize(1024, 9000)
        self.connect(self.web_page, SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), self.loadFinished)
        print('Before loading')
        self.web_view.load(QUrl(self.url))
        print('After loading')

    def loadFinished(self, ok):
        print('Start loadFinished()')
        print('Start writing')
        #with open('content_dd.txt', 'ab+') as fp:
            #fp.write(self.web_frame.toHtml().toUtf8())
        print('End writing')
        print('End loadFinished()')
        try:
            self.quit()
        except Exception as e:
            print('FATAL ERROR: %s' % (str(e)))

class NetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetworkAccessManager, self).__init__()
        # QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('finished (QNetworkReply *)'), self.finishd)

    def createRequest(self, operation, request, data):
        # url = request.url().toString()
        self.setNetworkAccessible(self.Accessible)
        return QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self, operation, request, data)

    def finishd(self, reply):
        print('In NetworkAccessManager finishd')
        url = str(reply.url().toString())
        log = '%s: %s\n' % (time.ctime(), url)
        #fp_log.write(log)
        print(reply)
        print(reply.request())
        print(log)
        print(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://need4bit.com'
    crawler = Crawler(url)
    sys.exit(crawler.exec_())
```

How should I modify this code so it could save all the resources into a directory.

Comment: What is the the point in using code that you didn't write and you don't understand? Even the author of this code states that it is buggy and doesn't fully work. Why don't you just use a third-party tool like [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) for website copying?

Comment: Wow this is just what I need, Is there a way that I can bundle this into my exe, because I cant supply my clients executables besides my own

Comment: The httrack website has information about licensing, and there is a forum where you can ask further questions. There is also a python extension: [httrack-py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/httrack-py/0.6). Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with httrack in any way, and I am not necessarily endorsing their software. Other website-copier tools are available ;-)